# How does one update a TextView's text in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, listener

I have a View in Android that has an onTouchEvent which stores the x and y values. In my Activity I have two TextViews that I initially set to 0 but would like to update them every time the View is clicked.

Can someone explain how to do this?

**Edit**

My Activity display 3 different Views and one of the Views has an onTouchEvent to see what the x and y position was if it was clicked.

```
public class MyActivity extend Activity {
    //LinearLayouts created to hold the Views


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //add buttons 
        for(Button b : myButtons) {
            buttonLayout.addView(b);
        }

        clickLayout.addView(clickView);    //ClickView is where I use the onTouchEvent and want to get the values from

        for(TextView tv : myTextViews) {
            //This is where I would like to set the text
            //It needs to update every time the ClickView's onTouchEvent happens
            textLayout.addView(tv);
        }
    }
}
```

If my ClickView source is necessary, let me know and I'll throw it up there. However, it just gets the X and Y.

The option that Dan S mentioned (passing textviews) is an option, however I was hoping there was a way my Activity could get ahold of the ClickView's onTouchEvent.

If there isn't an alternative way to those mentioned, I'll go ahead and mark this as solved since those aforementioned options do work, just slightly complicate the way I was working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onTouchEvent use this pseudo code

```
textViewX.setText(String.valueOf(motionEvent.getX()));
textViewY.setText(String.valueOf(motionEvent.getY()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that was precisely the reason I was asking, the TextViews are created in the Activity rather than in the View where the OnTouchEvent is. Should I create the TextViews in that View and pass them to the Activity?

Comment: Just use the onTouchEvent in the Activity or you could pass the TextViews to a your custom touchable widget.

Comment: @StartingGroovy: You could try Dan's suggestion but use the view's `getContext()` method and casting it to your activity class such as ((MyActivity)getContext()).textViewX - the TextViews will need to be `public`.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Would it be possible to do it from the Activity? I guess I'm asking if I'm able to see if the onTouch from the View has happened and if it has, grab to value? The reason I'm avoid the way you mentioned is because my TextViews aren't necessarily going to stay the same, there will be 2 - 6 at any given time

Comment: @Dan S I'm not sure what you mean by using the onTouchEvent in the Activity; are you wanting me to move my onTouchEvent code from my View to  my onTouchEvent in my Activity? I'll edit my main post to explain more as I have been too brief

Comment: @StartingGroovy I don't know the design of your program but my first thought would be to place it in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like the following...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        // Set clickView's OnTouchListener to be handled
        // by the onTouch(...) method of this Activity
        clickView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // The View parameter v will be the View that
        // was touched if you have more than one to handle
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are suggesting to switch to what Dan S mentioned?

Comment: Yes, but as you seemed slightly confused as to what he was suggesting and how to do it, I thought I'd give you an example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it's quite appreciated. Since Dan mentioned it prior, I'll go ahead and mark his as correct but also upvote you since each of your comments/posts have been helpful. If I have any issues, I'll leave another comment. Thanks for your time MisterSquonk

Comment: Glad I could help and no problem with you accepting Dan's answer. Thanks for the upvote, good luck.